# How to go about building a daily timeslot with php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working on a project where i was required to develop a timeslot system where employee can occupy a time slot within a specific day. I am using military time as my time format 00:00:00 - 23:00:00 and the days are from sunday - saturday. I just want them to book times for each day.

what is the correct mysql schema for this?
How do i go about handling validation, making sure that they only book for the available timeslots.

```
   ----------------------------------------------------
    USER_ID   |   DAY    |    STARTS_AT   |     ENDS_AT
    ----------------------------------------------------
              |          |                |          
              |          |                |       
              |          |                |       
              |          |                |       
              |          |                |       
   ------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: "How to go about building..." is typically not a good fit for StackOverflow. What have you tried so far? Please post your code.

Comment: Questions doesnt always start with an existing code. I was looking for a good approach on how to build timeslot availability system.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think the logic of which slot is available should be in your code, and then you simply keep record of which employee booked what time slot, using mysql datetime, don't think you need an extra day field, maybe something like id, user_id, start_time, end_time